# Дозволені мови / Allowed languages

Tags: discussion, rules, languages

<sub>Цей текст є спробою донести інформацію до користувачів, а не питанням — тим не менш ви можете висловлювати ваші думки, пропозиції, ідеї у коментарях/відповідях.</sub>

Ставити запитання і писати відповіді можна однією з двох мов: **українська** й **англійська** (звісно, зміст питання/відповіді має стосуватися української мови).

Трішки відрізняється політики щодо *«ме́ти»* (секції для технічних/організаційних обговорень — [Ukrainian Language meta](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/)):

- *Рекомендується* запитання/відповіді в ме́ті писати чи дублювати (відразу чи через деякий час) *англійською*. Особливо це стосується запитів щодо підтримки ззовні (наприклад, питань з тегами «support», «bug», «feature-request»). Особливо це стосується періоду, коли в нас немає внутрішніх модераторів. Також від себе хочу додати, що в нас є учасники спільноти, що не володіють українською, але активно нам допомагають (недубльовані обговорення вони можуть не зрозуміти).
- Тим не менш, це не обов'язково[<sup>[підтв.]</sup>](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/70/1231).

---

<sub>This text is a try to convey information to users, not a question — still you are allowed to express your thoughts, propositions, ideas within comments/answers.</sub>

It's allowed to ask questions and write answers in one of two languages: **Ukrainian** and **English** (of course, content of question/answer has to relate to the Ukrainian language).

The policies about *“meta”* (a section for technical/organizational discussions — [Ukrainian Language meta](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/)) are a bit different:

- It's *recommended* to write or dub (immediately or in some time) questions/answers within the meta in(to) *English*. Especially it relates to requests for support from outside (for example, questions with “support”, “bug”, “feature-request”). Especially it relates to a period we don't have internal moderators. Also I want to add from myself, that we have community members that don't know Ukrainian, but actively help us (they may be unable to participate in non-dubbed discussions).
- Never-the-less, it isn't obligatory[<sup>[підтв.]</sup>](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/70/1231).

Comment: Why does russian not allowed?

Comment: @br3t the Meta is for technical management and moderation of the site.

Comment: @br3t, Stack Exchange is quite conservative about allowing non-English text within questions and answers. Some time ago they allowed creating non-English sites, now they don't; and a site (of any language) doesn't allow Q&A in any language except the site's language. Our language *formally* is **English**, but as a language-learning site we have additional permission to use *target language* (i.e. Ukrainian) — nothing more. Initially I wanted to allow any language within Q&A (not only Russian, but Belarusian, Polish, etc) — but it isn't allowed by Stack Exchange rules now.

Comment: @br3t, references: [some time ago non-English sites were allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53004/252301), [then forbidden](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285279/252301), [language to use in language-related sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278299/252301), [remove non-English content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109051/252301), [target language is allowed](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/22595/146894).

Comment: I think whether Russian is allowed or not should be a question in its own right.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, well, there are two pitfalls: (1) I'm not sure we will be allowed to use more than 2 languages by higher SE policies at all (I suppose we won't). (2) I suppose the a debate for allowing/forbidding Russian would be hard and long (because some of native Ukrainian speakers really hate Russian: either due to long-ago history, or due to current politics, or due to smth else) and may take too much time of participants (especially during private beta). So, I [proposed](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/28/4#comment80_28) to Alex ask on general meta [to be continued…]

Comment: […continuation] about theoretical possibility of allowance to use 3rd language at all, before starting debates (whether majority of us wants it) within our meta. (However, maybe I was wrong, I don't know.)

Answer (score 5):

I'll share some experience from [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/). I don't speak Ukrainian, feel free to translate this post.

French Language was started mostly by French speakers and most regulars are more interested in questions by natives than in questions by learners. However, a majority of questions are currently in English. We accept questions in both languages, and accept answers in both languages. We encourage learners to try to write their question in French, but it is not compulsory. We encourage answerers to answer in the same language as the question, but only if they're familiar enough with the language; some answerers can decipher a question in English but not really write an answer in English, and it's fine if they answer in English.

French Meta is more bilingual than the main site: we translate the most important posts. Note that **Ukrainian is allowed on meta** (meta.ukrainian — on meta.french, French is allowed). This used to be officially forbidden, but French Meta has always allowed French. [Nowadays the site language *is* allowed on meta](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66/should-all-latin-question-titles-be-permitted/70#70). An English translation is encouraged, but it is only compulsory on posts that Stack Exchange staff must understand (e.g. bug reports). Meta should allow posts in either language, and someone should translate if necessary.

**Whether Russian is allowed here is a topic for the Ukrainian SE community to decide**. There is no real precedent of having a site with a lot of learners who share a language other than English. On French, this was [debated](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/may-i-ask-a-question-in-language-est-ce-que-je-peux-poser-une-question-dans) and the conclusion is that it's up to the asker to make themselves understood. But apart from one test question in the early beta, the case of a question that is neither in French nor in English never came up on French.SE... For Ukrainian.SE, it might be best to see how many people prefer asking (and getting answers?) in Russian over the course of the next few months.

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't know that meta is now allowed in target language. I oriented on [this](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/a/70): "we have to insist that any posts on the META site must be in English (or translated quickly after posted)" (although it was for *non-English* sites and *too old*, 2011). I'll update my text.

Comment: @Sasha The change in policy is quite recent and was not widely announced (it started out as a comment on some site meta, I think meta.esperanto…). But even before that, on French, we “resisted” and officially said meta posts in French were ok. Most posts on [meta.french.se] are in English anyway.

Answer (score -16):

I would like to suggest that Russian be allowed (albeit deprecated) on the Ukrainian.SE.  As suggested by Sasha, I was planning to post the following on the main Meta.SE.  If anyone would like to edit it to make it sound more well-presented, you are welcome.

> I believe Ukrainian language is in a unique position.  Ukraine used to
>   be a part of the Soviet Union, and everyone in Ukraine learned
>   Russian.  Ukrainian was considered the language of the village people.
>   A lot of people living in Ukraine and learning Ukrainian can only
>   speak Russian.  There is also a large group of people who actually
>   speak a mix of Ukrainian and Russian when they try to speak Ukrainian.
>   For example, they replace the soft sounds with hard sounds, "e" with
>   "i", and substitute the few words which they do know.
>
> I am among those in that position; however, I am fortunate enough that
>   I also know English, and can ask my questions in it.  My parents
>   don't-- they only speak Russian well.  Anyone who took German as a
>   second language is also in that position.  And most people my parents'
>   age who lived in cities only had Ukrainian as a "second language"--
>   and consequently don't know it well enough to ask questions in it. 
>   This is quite a large fraction of the Ukrainian people.
>
> For people in such circumstances, I suggest allowing asking questions
>   in Russian.  I don't mind this being a deprecated language, but it's
>   better than to simply throw such questions out.  When the official
>   StackExchange policy was formulated, no other languages were in the
>   same circumstance-- and hence the policy.

If the main Meta.SE decides to allow using Russian as a deprecated language, then we can vote on whether to allow it on these boards, and when [you can see an example disagreement in comments below].  We can also consider what being a deprecated language would entail.  For example, the answers could be encouraged to be given in Ukrainian.  Since Ukrainian is similar to Russian, most people my parents' age can understand answers given in Ukrainian-- just not speak it well themselves.  Or, the asker could tag it with "needs to be translated to Ukrainian".

Comment: You have two solutions:

Comment: 1. You can try to arise this question in general meta. Because I believe that higher SE policies don't allow third language (but I may be wrong).

Comment: That is precisely what I was planning to do, if the people on Ukrainian.SE supported it.

Comment: Actually, my though was that you should first ask on general meta whether it's theoretically possible — and only in case of positive answer we'll start debates (I suppose there'll be really great debates because *some* of native Ukrainian speakers really hate Russian: either due to long-ago history, or due to current politics, or due to smth else). But, of course, you can do it reverse order: first *start a separate discussion here (on meta.ukr)* and only then in case of positive solution here ask at general meta.

Comment: I just don't like a reverse order, because I don't want a lot of time to be lost in debates about something even theoretically impossible. (So, my idea is: (I) ask on general meta about probability of theoretical possibility [0% or 100% or 50% or what] for the case if we'll decide positively in future here; (II) then in case of non 0%-answer start debates here; (III) then in case of positive decision here ask about final verdict on general meta.)

Comment: As I've said you have two solutions. And the second is…

Comment: OK, good point.  So I think I can post on Meta.SE first-- as soon as I get a person or two who can help me improve what I say, so that it is well-presented on the Meta.  I will now update my question to reflect this goal.

Comment: 2. Wait for three month; or at least for three weeks; not to take into debates time of people who're trying to struggle us through private beta. Start discussion only then.

Comment: You can't up-vote your own questions.

Comment: I think I will go ahead and get the question ready to be presented on the Meta; by the time we get a decision, the three weeks can well pass.  `You can't up-vote your own questions.`  What was that about?

Comment: BTW, just a personal question: *Do you **really** nead to ask Russian?*. I mean: can't you ask in Ukrainian (even with mistakes) — or in surzhyk? Because it's hard for me to imagine such situation (and such environment / such part of Ukraine where such people — unable to speak Ukrainian at all — grow).

Comment: I believe this is a question that will come up once (and if) the Meta.SE approves our request.  From my point of view, Ukrainian needs to be kept pure-- otherwise we will have a trend progressively Russifying these forums.  So if you don't know how to ask in pure Ukrainian-- ask in what you know.  But again, that is probably better handled in its own thread if we get the approval.

Comment: «"You can't up-vote your own questions." What was that about?»  — Sorry, I'm just too tired, I accidentally misread «I will now update my question to reflect …» as «I will now upvote my question …».

Comment: «So if you don't know how to ask in pure Ukrainian-- ask in what you know [Russian].» Hmmm… No, per my opinion, no. Per my opinion it's better to ask in broken U. than in R. And [my original intent](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/22567/146894) was "allow any language, but endeavor to write in U., writing in others languages only if you feel you *won't be understood*" (not just in case you just can't speak *100%-correct*). And I'm too open-minded to forbid anything to anyone — but my personal opinion is that it's better to write in U. partially correct, than in R. or other language.

Comment: Again, this is probably handled better in a separate thread; however, the problem comes when people don't realize they are asking in broken Ukrainian, and people learning the language think that this is the right way to speak Ukrainian.  If you can get reasonably close to a correctly phrased Ukrainian question-- sure; but if you just substitute a few words you know, just stick with what you do know.

Comment: That's actually how language learning is done (U., R., E. — any language) — you just speak. Speak not 100%-correct, speak with mistakes, sometimes look funny/silly — but try speaking in target language. Assuming you arrive to USA/Germany/France — you can't say at market/bus-stop/office «I can't speak E./G./F. 100%-correct, so I'll speak R.» — the same should be here. That's my opinion.

Comment: Fair enough.  But someone who knows they can't speak German / French will acknowledge it, and likely tag their questions with "needs correction".  On the other hand, someone who thinks they know Ukrainian already will rarely acknowledge they need help.  And if they're not looking to learn, you correcting their question will not help them one bit.  This is a good point to bring up when I post in the Meta.SE.  Right now, I too am too tired to phrase this request coherently enough to post on there.

Comment: And there is two other problems with your logic, IMHO: (1) If someone thinks his U is good (even though it isn't), he wouldn't use R or E here. Therefore such idea (not to use U if feeling it isn't 100%-ok) *won't keep us from bad U*. People spending time to edit badly-worded questions may, but this idea — no. (2) A fact that someone speaks U badly doesn't necessarily mean that the one speaks R. He may speak R just as badly as U, or don't know R at all. So, IMHO, the idea "not to use U if feeling it isn't 100%-ok" is harmful. Still, I won't prevent you from searching possibilities to allow R.

Comment: Just my personal opinion is that users should *strongly* try to use U (if they want to learn/improve it, and we this site to succeed): "use other languages only when you feel your U is so bad that you will be misunderstood", not "use other languages when you feel your U isn't perfectly correct".

Comment: I just was going to ask how the process of asking about possibility-to-use-a-third-language on global meta is going, but see now that your post got a lot of down-votes. Well, this looks like a community opinion for me :-|. Still, you're still allowed to arise this topic anytime later if you wish.

Comment: Russian should not be allowed. Only Ukrainian and English should be allowed.